IAB TCF integration in wordpress cookie consent plugin not working
I am creating a wordpress plugin for GDPR Cookie consent. I am trying to integrate IAB TCF in my plugin. I have already created a banner for displaying on the website. I am getting vendor and purpose list using GVL, i am then taking consent from user and generating the TC STring. Now I wanted tt overify it on a validator. I installed cmp validator 2.2 chrom extension. Now the extension is getting details about cmp, i.e the cmp is getting initialized but even on giving consent, i am not able to see consents in the validator console.
This is the code for banner on front-end-
import { CmpApi } from "@iabtechlabtcf/cmpapi";
import { TCModel, TCString, GVL } from "@iabtechlabtcf/core";
import * as cmpstub from "@iabtechlabtcf/stub";
const cmpId = 1000;
const cmpVersion = 1500;

cmpstub();

GVL.baseUrl = "https://923b74fe37.nxcli.io/rgh/";


const gvl = new GVL();
console.log("GVL", gvl);

window.__tcfapi = function (command, version, callback, parameter = "") {
  console.log(
    `__tcfapi called with command: ${command}, version: ${version}, parameter: ${parameter}`
  );
  if (command === undefined) {
    console.trace("Undefined command triggered here");
  }

  if (command === "getTCData" && version === 2) {
    getTCData(callback, parameter);
  } else {
    callback({}, false); // Default response for unsupported commands
  }
};

window.__tcfapi.queue = window.__tcfapi.queue || [];
window.__tcfapi.loaded = true;

const tcModel = new TCModel(gvl);
var encodedString = "default tc string...";

function getTCData(callback, parameter) {
  console.log("getTCData function called");

  const sampleTCData = {
    tcString: tcModel.tcString,
    tcfPolicyVersion: tcModel.tcfPolicyVersion,
    cmpId: cmpId,
    cmpVersion: cmpVersion,
    gdprApplies: tcModel.gdprApplies,
    eventStatus: "tcloaded",
    cmpStatus: "loaded",
    isServiceSpecific: true,
    useNonStandardTexts: false,
    publisherCC: "DE",
    purposeOneTreatment: false,
    purpose: tcModel.purpose,
    vendor: tcModel.vendor,
    specialFeatureOptins: tcModel.specialFeatureOptins,
    publisher: tcModel.publisher,
  };

  callback(sampleTCData, true);
}

function initializeCMP() {
  console.log("CMP initialized.");
  checkForConsentStatus();
}

function checkForConsentStatus() {
  // Check if consent has already been given
  if (hasConsent()) {
    console.log("User has already given consent.");
  } else {
  }
}

function hasConsent() {
  // Logic to check if consent has been given
  return !!localStorage.getItem("userConsent");
}

initializeCMP();



gvl.readyPromise.then(() => {
  gvl.narrowVendorsTo([1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14]);
  console.log(gvl);
  if (iabtcf.consentdata.consent === "undefined")
    iabtcf.consentdata.consent = [];
  if (iabtcf.consentdata.legint === "undefined") iabtcf.consentdata.legint = [];
  if (iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_consent === "undefined")
    iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_consent = [];
  if (iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_legint === "undefined")
    iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_legint = [];
  if (iabtcf.consentdata.feature_consent === "undefined")
    iabtcf.consentdata.feature_consent = [];
  console.log("All vendor data");
  console.log(iabtcf.consentdata);

  tcModel.publisherCountryCode = "US";
  tcModel.version = 2;
  tcModel.cmpId = cmpId;
  tcModel.cmpVersion = cmpVersion;
  tcModel.gdprApplies = true;
  tcModel.isServiceSpecific = true;

  const cmpApi = new CmpApi(cmpId, cmpVersion, true);
});



(function ($) {
  "use strict";
  /**
   *  the IAB requires CMPs to host their own vendor-list.json files.  This must
   *  be set before creating any instance of the GVL class.
   */

  $(".gdpr_action_button").click(function (e) {
    var elm = $(this);
    var button_action = elm.attr("data-gdpr_action");
    if (button_action == "accept") {
      tcModel.gvl.readyPromise.then(() => {
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata.consent);
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata.legint);
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_consent);
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_legint);
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata.feature_consent);
        tcModel.vendorConsents.set(iabtcf.consentdata.consent.map(Number));
        tcModel.vendorLegitimateInterests.set(
          iabtcf.consentdata.legint.map(Number)
        );
        tcModel.purposeConsents.set(
          iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_consent.map(Number)
        );
        tcModel.purposeLegitimateInterests.set(
          iabtcf.consentdata.purpose_legint.map(Number)
        );
        tcModel.specialFeatureOptins.set(
          iabtcf.consentdata.feature_consent.map(Number)
        );

        // Set values on tcModel...
        encodedString = TCString.encode(tcModel);
        iabtcf.consentdata.tcString = encodedString;
        console.log("Here");
        console.log(iabtcf.consentdata);
        tcModel.tcString = encodedString;
        console.log(encodedString); // TC string encoded begins with 'C'

        window.__tcfapi("getTCData", 2, (tcData, success) => {
           if (success) {
             console.log("TC Data after accept:", tcData);
           } else {
             console.error("Failed to retrieve TC Data after accept");
          }
         });
        
      });
    }
  });

Now when I refresh my page i get following entries in console-
GVL z {readyPromise: Promise, gvlSpecificationVersion: undefined, vendorListVersion: undefined, tcfPolicyVersion: undefined, lastUpdated: undefined, …}

z {readyPromise: Promise, gvlSpecificationVersion: 3, vendorListVersion: 51, tcfPolicyVersion: 4, lastUpdated: Thu May 02 2024 21:37:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), …}

All vendor data

{consent: Array(3), legint: Array(2), purpose_consent: Array(12), purpose_legint: Array(6), feature_consent: Array(3), …}

__tcfapi called with command: undefined, version: undefined, parameter: 


This shows that __tcfapi is getting called on reload, now when i am clicking on accept button, i am getting following further entries in console
(3) ['12345', '6', '8']

 (2) ['12345', '8']

(12) ['12345', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']

 (6) ['12345', '2', '7', '8', '9', '10']

 (3) ['12345', '1', '2']

 Here

 {consent: Array(3), legint: Array(2), purpose_consent: Array(12), purpose_legint: Array(6), feature_consent: Array(3), …}allPurposeIds: (11) ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']allPurposesWithLegint: (5) ['2', '7', '8', '9', '10']allSpecialFeatureIds: (2) ['1', '2']allVendorsRejected: "false"allVendorsSelected: "false"allVendorsWithLegint: (4) ['8', '10', '11', '14']allvendorIds: (9) ['1', '2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '11', '12', '14']consent: (3) ['12345', '6', '8']feature_consent: (3) ['12345', '1', '2']legint: (2) ['12345', '8']purpose_consent: (12) ['12345', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']purpose_legint: (6) ['12345', '2', '7', '8', '9', '10']tcString: "CQDzioAQDzioAPoXcAENAzEsAP_gAEPAACiQAEAUACACAAAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA"

 CQDzioAQDzioAPoXcAENAzEsAP_gAEPAACiQAEAUACACAAAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA

As it is clear, the getTCData is not getting called as there is no entry for it in console. GVL is working fine as I am recieving the json. CLick function is working fine as other lines are getting consoled.Just the __tcfapi("getTCData") is not getting called as it should be.
Also attaching the validator console after i clicked on accept button-CMP Validator console
What is the issue and error?
